# How to refer to a parameterized method?

Tags: scala

Here is a code structure:

```
trait Foo[T <: Foo[_]] {
  def makeACopy[T](attr01_p: Option[String], ...): T
  ...
}

case class Bar extend Foo[Bar] {
  def makeACopy[Bar](attr01_p: Option[String], ...): org.myapp.domain.model.Bar = copy(attr01 = attr01_p, ...)
  ...
}
```

Now, a method in another class needs to refer to the method makeACopy.

```
class Qux(...){
  ...
  private def myMethod[T <: Foo](id: Long, getter: Long => Option[T], ...): Option[T] = {
    val b = getter(id)
    b match {
      case Some(bar) => bar.makeACopy[T](...) // <== It isn't right
      case None => ...
  }
}
```

I get a complying error for invoking the makeACopy method although I already specify the parameter as a sub-type of Foo and Intellij IDEA doesn't complain the line:

```
value makeACopy is not a member of type parameter T
```

Why? And how to solve it?

Also, I am not sure why I have to have a full path for returned data type of makeACopy in Bar. Otherwise, the IDE will complain returned type mismatch.

Comment: You must be lost in your `Foo`s and `Bar`s :) The reason you have to specify the package name in that return type kinda suggests that (there is more than one `Bar` probably). Also `[T <: Foo]` should not compile, because `Foo` needs to be parametrized, so, if you are not getting an error on that line, that kinda suggests, there is probably another `Foo` in scope ...

Comment: Thanks for your input. That doesn't seem to be my case. I only can find one of those classes with the names.

Comment: Whatever ... In any case, `Foo[T <: Foo]` is not valid code, maybe intellij is confused or something. You need to fix it before moving forward.

Comment: You are right. It shall trait Foo[T <: Foo[_]], which is what I have in my code. I missed the part when I did copy-n-paste.

Comment: `myMethod[T <: Foo]` is also invalid. This does not work. Don't try to copy the code piece-by-piece and rely on us to serve as a scala compiler for you.   Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: BTW, the reason it wants you to specify a package name is that `def makeACopy[Bar]` makes `Bar` a type parameter. You don't need the `[]` there (and you don't need it in the super definition either).

Comment: I clearly haven't had a good grip on the subject. Any online tutorial on this subject?

Comment: @TeeKai There's a number of good ones. You can shop around using Google, or try out http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf. Are you trying to learn Scala or just fix someone else's code?

Comment: Thanks Asad for the link. I am trying to do the both. I have pulled back my parameterized approach code changes because I need to meet a deadline. I will come back to this subject once I have more knowledge on parameterization .

Answer (score 1):

You're defining **two** separate type parameters named `T`, and only one of them as a subclass of Foo:

```
trait Foo[T <: Foo[_]] { // defining T once
  // that's another definition of a whole different T:
  def makeACopy[T](attr01_p: Option[String], ...): T
  ...
}
```

A method defined within a trait (or class) with a type parameter `T` shouldn't declare `T` again, so you probably want to change this to:

```
trait Foo[T <: Foo[_]] {
  // T used as return value is the one defined in trait:
  def makeACopy(attr01_p: Option[String], ...): T
  ... 
}
```

Then, wherever you call / override `makeACopy`, you don't need to specify the type, you already did when you created / extended `Foo`, e.g.:

```
case class Bar extend Foo[Bar] {
  def makeACopy(attr01_p: Option[String], ...): Bar = copy(attr01 = attr01_p, ...)
  ...
}
```